# error Warning: Undefined array key "name" #php

Tags: php, opencart-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQrLR.png)

show me how to fix this error , although there are quite a few posts but mine is a bit different . I don't understand php well thanks !
details of the error code line: $datainfo['category'] = $category['name'];

Comment: do print_r($category) and Check what result are you getting, As per the error, It's saying in $category array there is no field like "name"

Comment: And For handle error, you can write code like: $datainfo['category'] = (isset($category['name']))?$category['name']:"";

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA thanks so much , it worked for me ,  you saved me time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that PHP cannot find the key "name" in an array. To counteract the error, you can make the following check and assignment at the point where the array is set.

Many ways to do it:

**long version**

```
if (! isset($category['name'])) {
    $category['name'] = "";
}
```

**medium long version**

`$datainfo['category'] = (isset($category['name'])) ? $category['name'] : "";`

**shortest version**

`$datainfo['category'] = $category['name'] ?? "";`

Comment: long version will cause 1 more warning after 2 versions work normally

Comment: @dev99 what kind of warning you get. i tested and it works without warning. `<?php

if (! isset($category['name'])) {
    $category['name'] = "";
}

print_r($category);

Array
(
    [name] => 
)
`

Comment: no problem , problem solved , thanks .

Answer (score 1):

For handle error, you can write code like:

```
$datainfo['category'] = (isset($category['name']))?$category['name']:"";
```